# jQuery: Why would selector fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(".demo").click(function() {
     alert("JavaScript Demo");
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="demo">a paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why did not the click function response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running the code too early. You should wrap it in a document-ready handler, which jQuery supports thus:

```
$(function() {
  $(".demo").click(function() {
    alert("JavaScript Demo");
  });

  // Put other initialisation code here...
});
```

This will ensure that your code runs after the document is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You are running the code when the DOM isn't ready yet.

There are **2** solutions:

### **Solution One:**

Add the Javascript after the elements it affects. Preferably as far down the page as possible.

Doing this is not always possible, but it is **[suggested by YUI for speeding up your website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)**.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="demo">a paragraph</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     // This is after .demo
   $(".demo").click(function() {
     alert("JavaScript Demo");
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

### **Solution Two:**

Wrap your script in a doc ready. In jQuery there are **[several forms](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**. The quickest to type is `$(function() { ... });`:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     // doc ready
   $(function() {            
     $(".demo").click(function() {
       alert("JavaScript Demo");
      });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="demo">a paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should do it:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $(".demo").click(function() {
    alert("JavaScript Demo");
  });

    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="demo">a paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6sT32/)

Comment: `$(function() { ... })` is synonymous and a few keystrokes shorter ;)